# Hide all subprocesses when creating a process

Tags: c#, windows, process, subprocess, hidden

The arguments

```
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
CreateNoWindow = true,
```

Work only on the first created process. For example, if we call a cmd, which calls another cmd, only the parent will be hidden.

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = @"cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/K start cmd"
};
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

Is there a way to hide all subprocesses?

Answer (score 1):

No. You're hiding one specific window, and that's it. A process can show as many windows as it wants, and the same goes for starting new processes.

If you have control over the scripts you're running, you can use `start` with the `/B` argument, which allows you to start another process without creating a new window - but again, it is not "inherited"; you need to add it everywhere you want to avoid opening a new terminal.

Comment: The problem is that I run procmon.exe, which runs procmon64.exe, and thus it's visible. There isn't a way to get procmon64.exe itself as a file.

Comment: @Yair3230 You can use the `/minimized` argument to procmon to have it start minimized to the notification area (`/quiet` might also prove helpful). If that's not good enough for you, you can hide the window after the process starts, but that will show the window for at least a short while.